# Given a simple pandas Series, what's a simple way to create a histogram (bar plot) of it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a supersimple Series like this:

```
hour
0     438
1     444
2     351
3     402
4     473
5     498
6     440
7     431
8     259
9      11
11     52
12     62
13     77
14     55
22     40
23    162
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

It's just a count of the number of observations of something in a given hour. How could this be plotted quickly and easily as a histogram in a Jupyter notebook? The first bin would be from 0 to 1 hours (00:00 to 01:00), the second bin would be from 1 to 2 hours (01:00 to 02:00) and so on.

Comment: do you mean a simple bar plot: `ser.plot.bar()`?

Comment: `s.plot(kind='bar')` ?

Comment: have a look at `matplotlib` or my personal favorite `seaborn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need a standard bar plot:

```
In [8]: import matplotlib
   ...: matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
   ...:

In [9]: s.plot.bar(rot=0, grid=True, width=1, alpha=0.7)
Out[9]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xaaab7f0>
```

[image]

Comment: what version of pandas/matplotlib are you using? my default ggplot style has always looked as if `color='r'` argument has been passed. Sidenote, i always add the `edgecolor='k'` argument to my plots to add a black line inbetween bars

Comment: @MattR, pandas: 0.21.0, matplotlib: 2.1.0. Did you try to execute the snippet from my answer "as it is"? NOTE: old versions of Seaborn changed settings after executing  `import seaborn`, so you may want to close ipython/Jupyter and execute my snippet __not__ importing seaborn first

Comment: I actually don't have seaborn installed on this machine (work). Interesting how the style is still different..